# Proving A ==> B ==> C ==> B in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am puzzled about proving

```
A ==> B ==> C ==> B
```

in Isabelle. Obviously you could

```
apply simp
```

but how could I prove this with using rules?

Alternatively, is there a way to dump the rules `simp` used? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to understand how proofs work, you should forget both about funny tactics and automated reasoning tools as a start.

The statement `A ==> B ==> C ==> B` (using this special `==>` connective) of Isabelle/Pure is immediately true, so its proof in Isabelle/Isar is:

```
lemma "A ==> B ==> C ==> B" .
```

That's it, just `.` (which abbreviates `by this`, but the `this` is actually empty here).

As slightly less vacuous proof uses actual Isabelle/HOL connectives, which you can then handle by standard introduction or elimination steps.  E.g. like this:

```
lemma "A --> B --> C --> B"
proof
  show "B --> C --> B"
  proof
    assume b: B
    show "C --> B"
    proof
      show B by (rule b)
    qed
  qed
qed
```

But that is not so interesting either: you build up a boring implication that that is then decomposed until you are finished.

To find more interesting Isabelle/Isar proofs just do some web search, or look through the sources that come with the system.
A totally arbitrary example is here: [Drinker](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL-Isar_Examples/Drinker.html).

There are also tons of manuals, actually too many of them.

Comment: Thank you for your solution and recommendations! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can enable simplifier tracing; in Proof General, you can do this with Isabelle → Settings → Tracing → Trace Simplifier, I don't know about jEdit.

EDIT: In this case the simp trace will not be very helpful, since `simp` does not use rewrite rules to solve this, instead it "sees" A, B, and C in the premises and concludes that it can, in the context of this statement, rewrite `A = True`, `B = True`, and `C = True`, then it rewrites the goal `B` to `True` and you're done.

However, the "normal" way of proving statements such as this is to use the `assumption` method, which matches the goal against a premise, in this case `B`. There is probably a way to prove this using `rule` as well, but that would be unnecessarily complicated. `assumption` uses `assume_tac`, which in turn is just a wrapper around the *very basic* function `Thm.assumption`, so this can really be considered one of the most elementary proof methods in Isabelle.
So just write `by assumption`.

Comment: The information by Manuel is inaccurate.  You hardly ever see `by assumption` in proper Isar proofs -- that is already implicit in the closing of the proof.